# PhantomJS error on basic tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, phantomjs

I'm using the `node-phantom` npm module, and whenever I do a super simple test like

```
phantom=require('node-phantom');
var phantom=require('node-phantom');
phantom.create(function(err,ph) {
    console.log("testing");
    ph.exit();
});
```

It prints the following error:
`phantom stdout: console msg:XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1439501157936-0. Origin http://127.0.0.1:60689 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

Anyone know what the cause of this could be?

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-exec": "^0.4.6",
    "mocha": "^2.2.5",
    "node-phantom": "^0.2.5",
    "phantom": "^0.7.2",
    "phantomjs": "^1.9.18",
  }
}
```

(there are multiple versions of phantom because I've been trying some out)

Comment: Show us the package.json and the command you execute `npm test`?

Comment: Try [phantom](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node) instead of [node-phantom](https://github.com/alexscheelmeyer/node-phantom). It has basically the same API, but a different communication setup. Are you on windows by the way?

Comment: @EmilioPlatzer I'm running the script directly with `node test.js` (my file is called `test.js`). Not trying to tie in with a test suite right now, literally just trying to get my environment set up and nothing is working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changed `window.location.hostname` to `window.location.host` in `node-phantom.js` file.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I found this too. This technically works, but I wish there's a better way.